# How to compute change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $v_1=(2,2,1,3)$ and $v_2=(0,1,1,1)$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, and let $V$ be the subspace which is the span of these two vectors.

According to what I am working on, there exists a basis for $V$ of the form $w_1=(1,a,0,b)$ an $w_2=(0,x,1,y)$ with integer $a$,$b$,$x$, and $y$.

I have tried figuring out the basis in a sort of ad hoc way. But there is a systematic way to compute such a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build $w_1$ out of $v_1$ and $v_2$. To get the first component, $v_2$ is useless, so you have to take 1/2 of $v_1$. That gives you (1,1,1/2,3/2).  To make the third component zero, you have to subtract enough copies of $v_2$ to get rid of the 1/2.  Since $v_2$ has a 1 in that place, you subtract $\frac{1}{2}v_1$ to get $$(1,1,1/2,3/2) - (0, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2) = (1, 1/2, 0, 1) = w_1$$
You find the other vector similarly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to state in the problem that $a,b,x$ and $y$ are integers.

Comment: Given your constraints, the problem is not solvable, is it?  $2w_1$ does not have a $1$ in the first component.

Comment: It seems not, but it should be...

Comment: I was able to find an error in my computation, which messed up one of the assumptions that gives that this will always be integers. I think it will work out to be integers now that I've corrected the mistake. Thanks for the help.